# Using file outside of template hierarchy for Twitter sign in authentication

Tags: templates, redirect

I'm trying to use a file for my Twitter sign in authentication callback that isn't in the traditional WordPress template hierarchy.

This is a problem I generally want to solve away from this one instance.

How do you use a file within a template for things like login authentication without receiving a 404?

Current file setup:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

// oauth.php. Your callback File

if ( isset($_GET['oauth_token']) ) {

    // ---------- CODE

    // redirect to main page
    header('Location: front-page.php');

    // ---------- CODE
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to use a template file, why do you use `define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);`? Is your script directly executed or is it executed in WordPress context?

Comment: @cybmeta I worded it wrong, apologies. It's a none template file and it's to be executed directly, redirecting the user back to the homepage

Comment: I think is possible that you get the 404 Not found error because of the wrong use of `header('Location: front-page.php');`. The location must be a URL. Try `header( 'Location: ' . esc_url_raw( get_home_url() ) );` or similar.

Comment: @cybmeta I'm now getting an 'internal server error'. I've stripped the file back to just ``define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
header( 'Location: ' . esc_url_raw( get_home_url() ) );
exit;``

Comment: The issue before was that I didn't just .php at the end of the callback URL...school boy error :)

Comment: Impossible to know what happened. `esc_url_raw` and `get_home_url` are WP functions, but you are out of WordPress. Trye with a hardcoded URL first. I'm sure that `header('Location: front-page.php');` generates de 404 error because it is used as relative URL. For example, if you are in `http:://mydomain.com/some-page/` the redirection will be to `http:://mydomain.com/some-page/front-page.php`, which generates 404 error if `some-page/front-page.php` is not a real file/path/URL, which is pretty sure it is not.